# what difference between del [[var]] and del var python

Tags: python, python-3.x

hello every one sometime i'm reading some other source code

today i seen someone type `del [[var_name]]`

but i know in python if you want delete you can type `del var_name`

so i need ask what **different between del [[var]] and del var**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no real difference.

The `del` statement can be given a single variable, or an iterable containing variables. If it's given an iterable, it processes it recursively, deleting all the variables it contains. This allows you to write

```
del var1, var2, var2
```

But it can also be a list, or a list of lists, so you can write

```
del [var1, [var2, var3]]
```

Since it's recursive, you can nest them as deep as you want, e.g.

```
del [[[[[var_name]]]]]
```

Comment: It's not really an "iterable containing variables". You can't have an iterable of variables, and if you tried to use a set or a deque or some other iterable type, it wouldn't work. It's a ["target list"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement), which is a syntactical construct that looks like the literal syntax for lists and tuples, but a bit more restrictive.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I was trying to use a familiar term that would encompass both the tuple `var1, var2, var3` and the list `[var1, var2, var3]`.